# contact listener,who touch who?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i always use the contact listener in this way :

```
b2Body *bodyA=contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyB=contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
.
.
CCSprite *actora = (CCSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData(); 
CCSprite *actorb = (CCSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData();
.
.
if ([actora tag] == 6  &&  ( [actorb tag]== 4 || [actorb tag]== 5 )  ) // question !!
//do stuff here
```

now i find my self always try to guess who is actora and who is b.
lets say that some body is flying and hit another body. sometimes the hitten body is a and the other one is b and vise versa.

i dont want to check all conditions, and want to know whats the algorithm to know that .
i was thinking that the first body on screen gets the a (first defined sprite) .
that was right, till i found it wrong :)

so , how would i know a/b who is which ? (is it random ?? )

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

See all `body` in `space` is linked through a linked list and you have to travel the list to get the required element, it's not like a `array` through which we can select any element without traveling the list.

So, In our case this is a linked list and we have to travel through the link path and we don't know which body we will get first So we have to examine both condition. No other way to find that.

So it looks random :-)

It's all is linked list.

Thanks

Comment: got you. BUT i am sure there is some kind of routine when moving on a list, for example , i have seen that ALWAYS bodies which where first created, are called first . think about it, its a class that someone wrote, i am pretty sure there is some rule to know who will be called first in a certain condition ..i have proved that already.